# Dynamic search through a Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm running into a dilemma, i'm trying to create a function to "dynamically" search trough an array, in this case my session array, but it should be for any. Now that is not my problem, my problem is to dynamically allow this to be done...

Here's what i have

```
public static function get($search = 'First/Second/Third') {    
    $explode = explode('/',$search);
    $count = count($explode);
    if ($count == 1)
        if (isset($_SESSION[$explode[0]]))
            return $_SESSION[$explode[0]];
    elseif ($count == 2)
        if (isset($_SESSION[$explode[0]][$explode[1]]))
            return $_SESSION[$explode[0]][$explode[1]];
    elseif ($count == 3)
        if (isset($_SESSION[$explode[0]][$explode[1]][$explode[2]]))
            return $_SESSION[$explode[0]][$explode[1]][$explode[2]];
}
```

So let's say i have an array:

```
 array('First' => array('Second' => array('Third' => 'TEST VALUE'));
```

Now i want to call

```
$value = get('First/Second/Third');
```

and then get "Test Value" back as the value for my $value variable.

In this situation it works, but it just isn't dynamic, and I want it to be able to handle maybe even a 10 layer deep array as well, without adding more and more lines....

Well maybe someone out here smarter then me :)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$array = array(
        'First' => array(
                'Second' => array(
                        'Third' => 'TEST VALUE'
                )
        )
);
echo get($array, 'First/Second/Third'); //  TEST VALUE
```

**Function Used**

```
function get($data, $part) {
    foreach(explode("/", $part) as $key) {
        $data = isset($data[$key]) ? $data[$key] : null;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://eval.in/32773)

Comment: This is a great solution. I am ashamed to admit I recurred to eval() when I had this problem once.

Comment: But why the ``$data = isset($data[$key]) ? $data[$key] : null`` in stead of just ``$data = $data[$key]``? If there is no such key, ``$data`` will be null?!?

Comment: @Andri i hope you can update your code not .. using `eval` is not a good solution at all

Comment: @Baba No worries, that project was tossed aside unfinished and has never seen the light of production.

Comment: I can see you'll get an undefined index warning without it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$data = $_SESSION;
foreach(explode('/', $seach) => $pos) {
    $data = $data[$pos];
}
return $data;
```

Comment: change `=> $pos,` into `as` ... and put a `;` after `$data = $data[$val]` and it should work

Comment: Yes. You're right. Confused by not using values for anything but counting.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. it does a recursive tree search. In the event that no match is found it will return a `false` else it will return the branch or leaf at the desired path.

```
     function treeSearch($query, $array, $currentDepth = 0){
           if (is_string($query)) $query = explode("/", $query);
           $term = $query[$currentDepth];
           if (isset($array[$term])){
               if ($currentDepth == count($query)-1){
                    // we found it
                    return $array[$term];
               } else {
                    return treeSearch($query, $array[$term], ++$currentDepth);
               }
           } else {
              // no matching branch;
              return false;
           }

     }
```

example Usage

```
    $array = array('First' => array('Second' => array('Third' => 'TEST VALUE')));
    print_r(treeSearch("First/Second", $array));
    print_r(treeSearch("First", $array));
    print_r(treeSearch("First/Second/Third", array));
```